# Coding for a Multiplayer + Singleplayer game Kit for developers

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I currently have a 2D RPG Kit in the Unity asset store and want to add Multiplayer capability to it as well as it still be able to be played in single player mode.  I went through the tutorials in [Unity Multiplayer Networking Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking) and everything went smooth and I was able to understand how to code just for a multiplayer game on a very basic level.  But I am kind of unsure or rather not confident about my approach I want to take for creating both aspects in my current project.

What I was initially going to do was just make copies of my scripts and then edit them to for Network purposes (NetworkBehavior, [Command], SyncVar, etc).  I was wanting to hear from some people who have done something like this before I go all code crazy and end up wasting time lol.  I feel like copies would be the most simple approach so if they wanted single player scripts it would be a drag and drop of single player scripts and the same goes for network scripts.  Also if I happen to botch a network script then the singleplayer scripts will not be affected.  Is this a smart approach for what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exact same network scripts as well, the only difference is that you create a localhost server and you're the only player connected.

Commands, SyncVars, ClientRPCs, NetworkBehaviours ... stay all the same.

Comment: Thank you Jansen.

Comment: One question, doing it this way will not have any performance problems will it for single player?  Will performance with single player with no network code be very similar to single player with network and running a local host?

Comment: @JoeyL since you don't need to send messages through the network there is no latency affecting the performance.